# Invalid SQL statement expected; ‘DELETE’,’INSERT’,

Tags: excel, adodb, vba

I have a code

```
Dim Cn As New ADODB.Connection

Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
Dim i As Long

Cn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
    "Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & ";" & _
    "Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;"""
Cn.Open
cmd.ActiveConnection = Cn
cmd.CommandText = "DECLARE @TS_HD DOUBLE;" & _
"SET @TS_HD = ?TS_HD;" & _
"SELECT So_HD, Ngay_HD, Ten_Khach_Hang, Ma_So_Thue, Sum(Doanh_So_KT) as DoanhSo, Sum(Thue_VAT) as VAT from [BR$] " & _
"Where Ngay_HD <> null And TS_HD = @TS_HD Group by So_HD, Ma_So_Thue,Ngay_HD, Ten_Khach_Hang Order by Ngay_HD"

Set TS_HD = cmd.CreateParameter("?TS_HD", adDouble, adParamInput)
cmd.Parameters.Append TS_HD
TS_HD.Value = 0.1          'in excel this value is 10%'

Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
Set rst = cmd.Execute()

BRToTalKhongChiuThue() = rst.GetRows

rst.Close
Cn.Close
```

Is that something worng when i ran this code VBA show Error "Invalid SQL statement expected; ‘DELETE’,’INSERT’,"
Thanks for see my question !

Comment: Please link to the cross-post next time you ask on more than 1 site. Ideally, only ask on 1 site - the question is likely only on-topic on one site anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax for your parametered query doesn't look right.

> ```
> DECLARE @TS_HD DOUBLE;
> SET @TS_HD = ?TS_HD;
> SELECT 
>      So_HD
>     ,Ngay_HD
>     ,Ten_Khach_Hang
>     ,Ma_So_Thue
>     ,SUM(Doanh_So_KT) AS DoanhSo
>     ,SUM(Thue_VAT) AS VAT 
> FROM [BR$]
> WHERE Ngay_HD <> NULL AND TS_HD = @TS_HD 
> GROUP BY 
>      So_HD
>     ,Ma_So_Thue
>     ,Ngay_HD
>     ,Ten_Khach_Hang
> ORDER BY 
>      Ngay_HD
> ```

I'm not sure the provider supports `DECLARE` statements. If it doesn't, that's why you're getting this message. Let's try to remove it:

```
SELECT 
     So_HD
    ,Ngay_HD
    ,Ten_Khach_Hang
    ,Ma_So_Thue
    ,SUM(Doanh_So_KT) AS DoanhSo
    ,SUM(Thue_VAT) AS VAT 
FROM [BR$]
WHERE Ngay_HD <> NULL AND TS_HD = ?
GROUP BY 
     So_HD
    ,Ma_So_Thue
    ,Ngay_HD
    ,Ten_Khach_Hang
ORDER BY 
     Ngay_HD
```

Notice the WHERE clause, `WHERE Ngay_HD <> NULL AND TS_HD = ?` - the parameter placeholder is just a question mark.

I'm pretty sure that statement would work.

I'm less sure about how the parameter is passed in though:

```
Set TS_HD = cmd.CreateParameter("?TS_HD", adDouble, adParamInput)
```

I think you can drop the name parameter, it's optional - and some providers don't support named parameters. That sucks though, because now you need to *name the arguments* since the `Name` parameter is first in the signature of `CreateParameter`:

```
Set TS_HD = cmd.CreateParameter(Type:=adDouble, Direction:=adParamInput)
```

An alternative could be to `New` it up and initialize it "manually":

```
Dim param As New ADODB.Parameter
With param
    .Type = adDouble
    .Direction = adParamInput
    .Value = 0.01    'in excel this value is 10% '?? really? it's 1% here!
End With

cmd.Parameters.Append param
```

Comment: Many thanks @Mat's Mug !!! But how can i put a variable to param.value and Execute() Recordset agian. Example : 0.1 change to 0.05 and 0 ???